# Measure server HttpRequest's performance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, httprequest, performance-testing

How to measure server HttpRequest's performance?

I think it's important task and many peoples solved this challenge.

I will explain.
I have many user server requests which calls in parallel and i want measure some Performance metrics of identical requests.

For example:

```
10:00:00AM request 1 duration 200 ms: /some_request/data
...
11:00:00AM request 2 duration 700 ms: /some_request/data
...
11:30:00AM request 3 duration 300 ms: /some_request/data
...
```

As you can see the general problem is that duration of requests always jumped, and we can't say about real change of request performance. Difference between duration of identical request's (note: with same json data 1-1) can be unpredictable.

In example i try measure requests duration like that:

```
public class PerformanceFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        timer.Reset();
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        var duration = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

May be it's wrong way? Or for detecting of request performance change we can use other request characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the w3c HTTP log value time-taken as an objective method for collecting your timing data?  This is taken at the server and misses only the last ack on the finish of the send as a part of the time collection.

One thing you will want to be particularly careful of is when your sample agent or your server is inside of a virtual machine as this impacts clock precision and integrity.  The virtual machine clock is unpinned from the hardware clock and "floats."  In this float period the clock does slow/degrade slightly and periodically has to be resync'd to the hardware clock.  Invariably this will happen when you are timing an event on the virtual machine.  This results in an apparent jump in the timed event.

This is a well known problem in the performance testing community which has to design around clock float issues related to timing precision on performance tests where virtual machines are used as load generators.

Comment: Great explanation, but how to reduce or remove this “floats” behaviour from virtual machines? Or it’s not “simple”?

Comment: You cannot manage the float.  This is a natural behavior of the time slicing which goes on in software virtualization environments.   The hypervisor makes the decision on when to sync and how often.  In performance testing we manage the float with control elements, specifically a single machine running small numbers of test agents on physical hardware.  We can estimate the skew by looking at the difference in behavior from the control group on physical hardware to the remainder running on virtual machines.  Think of this like six sigma manufacturing quality control sampling

Comment: How about some other metrics, (not duration) for example “cpu usage”. Can we measure http request performance with it?

Comment: Does your VM autoscale.  You can only report what the hypervisor tells you.   The truth is available from the hypervisor via command line tools and SNMP management tools, but you would only have this in a private cloud model, not a public cloud one.

Comment: hmm, ok. Understood. But if i move my performance expirements to physical machine (not vm)? It’s improve situation with requests duration?

Comment: If your request jumps are due to clock jump/resync, which you will always be subject to in a virtualized environment, then what you will find is that your avg, median, 90th percentile and population standard deviation narrows because the integrity of your timing record has improved without the jump'd values

Answer (score 1):

Can you use any tool to measure the performance? If yes give a try with Fiddler..When you make a connection to a website fiddler will start tracking all the requests and responses and from there you select a request and right click - > go to properties and there you can see all the time stamps for the request and response. Hope this helps

Comment: Tools it’s not problem, but i sure that it’s not solved the jumps of request duration.